# How can i make my embedded pdfs responsive screen size?

Tags: html, reactjs

Hey i have a pdf file and would like to make it responsive to screen size. how would i do that?

```
<div 
        style={{
            display: 'flex',
            alignItems: 'center',
            justifyContent: 'center',
            height: '100vh',

        }}
    >
          <embed
                id='pitch'
                src={pdfSample}
                type="application/pdf"
                height={800}
                width={800}
            />
    </div>
```

Comment: @KJ into my embed tag or my style?

Comment: @KJ i have tried that and my pdf is not responsive. it does not resize in accordance to screen size.

Comment: so use iframe? @KJ

Answer (score 0):

Pdf viewers have independent controls compared to the html page so often result is not consistent across browsers or their extensions. For my given settings this works:-

[image]
[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
     "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
  <meta HTTP-EQUIV=CONTENT-TYPE CONTENT="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <title>Page 1</title>
<style>
body, .my_pdf { min-height: 95vh; }
</style>
</head>
<body text="#000000" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" link="#000080" vlink="#0000CC" alink="#000080">
<center>
   <div 
        style={{
            display: 'flex',
            alignItems: 'center',
            justifyContent: 'center',
            height: '100vh',

        }}
    >
          <embed class="my_pdf"
                id='pitch'
                src="out.pdf#view=FitV"
                type="application/pdf"
                width=800px
            />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

In this Mozilla based browser with a different extension the user can set mode so it works in some chosen cases but not others. Generally for PDFs you can suggest desired browser view setting but not force them.

[image]

Comment: i am using react btw-